# How to change excel cell or column format using php?

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php 
if($_POST) {
//here i give test $result datas
$result = array(array("Date"=>"2016-01-01","Time"=>"01:08:06","num"=>"0123456789","amount"=>"0.12"),    array("Date"=>"2016-01-02","Time"=>"02:08:06","num"=>"1234567890","amount"=>"1.12"),array("Date"=>"2016-01-03","Time"=>"03:08:06","num"=>"1234567899","amount"=>"3.12")
    );
    require_once "phpexcel/class.writeexcel_workbook.inc.php";
    require_once "phpexcel/class.writeexcel_worksheet.inc.php";
    $fname = tempnam("/tmp", "simple.xls");
    $workbook = &new writeexcel_workbook($fname);

    $f_volume =& $workbook->addformat();
    //$f_volume->set_align('left');
    $f_volume->set_num_format('@');

    $gen =& $workbook->addformat();
    $gen->set_align('left');
    $gen->set_num_format('General');


    $dat =& $workbook->addformat();
    //$dat->set_align('left');
    $dat->set_num_format('DD/MM/YYYY');

    $inv_ref =& $workbook->addformat();
    $inv_ref->set_num_format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');

    $setup =& $workbook->addformat();
    $setup->set_align('left');
    $setup->set_num_format('#,###.00#');

    $tax =& $workbook->addformat();
    $tax->set_align('left');
    $tax->set_num_format('0.###%');

    $worksheet = &$workbook->addworksheet("My Report");

    $worksheet->write_string(0,0,'Date');
    $worksheet->write_string(0,1,'Time');
    $worksheet->write_string(0,2,'Dialled');
    $worksheet->write_string(0,3,'Rate');


    $worksheet->set_column(0,0,10,$dat);
    $worksheet->set_column(0,1,10,$f_volume);
    $worksheet->set_column(0,2,20,$f_volume);
    $worksheet->set_column(0,3,10,$f_volume);



    $j=1;
    $unitTotal = 0;
    $totalTotal = 0; 
    if(count($result) > 0 ) {
        foreach($result as $outKey=>$rr){
            $worksheet->write($j,0,date("d/m/Y",strtotime($rr['Date'])));
            $worksheet->write($j,1,$rr['Time']);
            $worksheet->write($j,2,$rr['Dialled']);
            $worksheet->write($j,3,$rr['Rate']);
        }
    }

    $workbook->close();

    //header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; name=Calls Report.xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Calls Report.xls");
    $fh=fopen($fname, "rb");
    fpassthru($fh);
    unlink($fname);
}
?>
```

i have used above mentioned code to generate "My Report" excel and its working well, the problem is after open excel right click over the cell->Format Cells
then its shows text format but i need to show if i select date then format is Date,if time then format is Time, if its amount then format is  Currency, i have used "$dat" to set Date format here but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

From the libraries documentation, downloadable from their github repo...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A6')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME
    );
```

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/PHPExcel%20developer%20documentation.doc

Does that achive what you want? I'm not able to test it myself right now.

Comment: Although, it looks like you could be using a different / older version of the library. Are you sure the libarary you're using supports what you want to do?

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the library you are using would normally be several steps before coming to SO saying that something doesn't work how you expect.

Comment: just in excel date record must save as date format, time as time format and Rate as currency format

Comment: Link to documentation?

Comment: OP isn't using PHPExcel; I think they're using the old PEAR Spreadsheet Excel Writer library